# Files are not packed when importing package.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json

I'm writing a cli package and for showing the version I'm importing `version` from `package.json`.

When I do that, after running `tsc` the dist folder looks like that:

```
/dist
--/package.json
--/README.md
--/src
----files
----...
```

the `package.json` has the following property:

```
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
```

I use `npm pack` to see what will be part of the tarball.
when I try to pack it, only 3 files are packed:

```
npm notice 1.9kB dist/package.json
npm notice 1.7kB package.json     
npm notice 1.2kB README.md
```

but If I don't import the version from `package.json`, it is no longer in the `dist` directory and all the content in `dist` gets packed properly.

As a temporary measure I'm reading `package.json` with `fs`, but that's far an elegant solution.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue caused by npm, downgrading permission (ran as root on the ci), adding to the npm config `unsafe-perm` solved it.